# Streamline pricing sheet to many different formats?

Tags: php, sql, xml, excel

At my company we have a master pricing sheet in Excel that we keep updated. However, we have marketing materials in InDesign, Excel, on our website (with a MYSQL database), and 3rd party websites. Every month we update our prices, we have to update all of them by hand which is a lot of work, and prone to errors.

I am sure with all that is out there today, there is a way to streamline all of this from our master sheet, so we only have to update the master, and the rest can be automatically updated..

Can anyone suggest a solution for me, or at least a good direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach i would take is to move the master sheet into a database.  This would allow me to create a simple web based gui that uses web services and role based authentication.  The web services would generate xml, csv, etc.  This would further allow for central management of pricing which in turn prevents rogue managers / sales people from hurting the company's bottom line.

Answer (score 1):

I don't disagree with Woot4Moo's suggestion, however business reality (cost, experience, ongoing maintenance) may prevent you from moving off Excel as the master price list.  Fortunately Excel works fine as an ODBC-compliant data source for simple queries.

Assuming the master Excel sheet is in an accessible location (i.e. on a shared network drive, not someone's PC), you can create ODBC connections from MySQL, Excel, and InDesign to pull data.  3rd-party web sites will probably be more difficult, given they won't have access to your network (this would be true even if you migrated to an internal RDBMS, although you could create APIs).

See [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel) and [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2007) for examples of Excel connection strings.

Comment: There are undoubtedly elements of truth in what you say, but you lose tracability, in particular, if your master document is the Excel spreadsheet.  You'd be better off, in general, creating the Excel from the data in the DBMS, I think.  It does assume you have a decent way of entering the data.  You might be able to arrange to import changes from a spreadsheet too.  I'm a DBMS person; I don't trust spreadsheets (they're too malleable and fungible).

Comment: Totally agree @Jonathan... but reality often blocks progress.  Going with a real RDBMS would be my first choice, but I disagree that they may lose tracability -- they don't have it right now to lose.  Excel is the current master, and changing that could be difficult: a) the company may not have anyone with any DBA experience, b) users may complain that updating prices in Excel is so much easier than a new interface (often this is a valid complaint) c) cost - this doesn't sound like a particularly tech-savvy company, they may need consultants, etc.